# Foreach Loop in PHP only Once

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop but i want level only print once like example below.

https://prnt.sc/wgm877

But when i try foreach loop it print again and again.

https://prnt.sc/wgmazh

```
          <?php foreach($rooms as $room) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $room->Level; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $room->Type; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $room->Dimension; ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it like this. I.e. "remember" the last room level for each iteration. If it's changed, then print the new room level, otherwise print an empty string:

```
<?php 
$lastlevel = "";
foreach($rooms as $room) { 
    if ($lastlevel != $room->Level) {
        $level = $room->Level;
        $lastlevel = $level;
    } else {
        $level = "&nbsp;";
    }
    $nextrow = <<<EOD
         <tr>
            <td>{$level}</td>
            <td>{$room->Type}</td>
            <td>{$room->Dimension}</td>
         </tr>
EOD;
    echo $nextrow;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the structure and do a foreach on the levels instead of the rooms, or use a new variable to know if the level has already been displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
<? foreach ($actions as $action): ?>
    <option value="<?= $action ?>"><?= $action ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

If you want to implement php on the frontend with html, I recommend doing it in the following way.